# Copy files from Folder A to Folder B based on Text File C with bash

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

How do I copy files from Folder A to Folder B based on Text File C with bash?

- folderA: source folder with image files only, e.g. `image01.png`, `image02.png` etc. There are no space in the image names, only dash or underscore
- folderB: destination folder with nothing inside.
- C.txt: is a UTF16 encoded raw text file, inside the text file stored the file names that I want to copy from folderA  and these file names are line by line

  ```
  image01.png
  image02.png
  image04.png
  ```

Specific paths are

- `~/Documents/C.txt`
- `~/Documents/folderA/`
- `~/Documents/folderB/`

Comment: What do you mean "based on text file C"?  Can you provide an example of how you expect this to work?

Comment: I'm glad that you found a solution but the solution doesn't match your question- "How do I copy files from one directory to another based on a text file with filenames"

Comment: I don't think so fd0, I do exactly this :  I changed directory to folderA  then 'cp argument1 argument2'  where argument 1 is a chain of file names that I want and separated by a space;  argument2 is the destination.  Talking is unreal, test it in your local host.

Comment: Please don‘t add the answer to the Question, Post it as an answer below instead. It might also help to make sure the formatting is correct, and to show how you use `C.txt` in your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your file C contains a list of file names to copy:

```
A="~/Documents/folderA"
B="~/Documents/folderB"
while IFS= read -r file; do
    cp "${A}/${file}" "${B}/"
done < ~/Documents/c.txt
```

should do the trick.

Comment: cd ~/  to change director
cp (paste chain of file names here now) (then, type a space)  then type your destination folder path/name (hit return)

Comment: this link will help any newbies :  https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/4614926-learn-the-command-line-in-terminal/4634381-move-and-copy-items-in-your-system

Comment: Tried many times, this script doesn't work for me.

Comment: @gcplau What exactly doesn‘t work?